# Error when executing Java code with nested class

Tags: java, runtime-error, inner-classes, main-method

newbie here. Tried executing Java class that has a nested class and I keep getting this
`Error: Could not find or load main class .`
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
When I compiled the source code, I got two new **.class** files; **ShadowTest$FirstLevel.class** and **ShadowTest.class**. The error shows up when I try to execute either one. Please help.

Here's the code

```
public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which command do you use to compile and then run the file(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always compile the class with **javac *filename*** command. Then execute the code with command **java main_class_name**

```
javac ShadowTest.java
java ShadowTest
```

/** output **/

```
x = 23
this.x = 1
ShadowTest.this.x = 0
```

Inner classes, if any present in your class, will be compiled and the class file will be ClassName$InnerClassName.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to replicate the issue you are facing by following the below steps.**

- I have created a java file "**ShadowTest.java**" with your code.

> ```
> public class ShadowTest {
>
>     public int x = 0;
>
>     class FirstLevel {
>
>         public int x = 1;
>
>         void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
>             System.out.println("x = " + x);
>             System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
>             System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String... args) {
>         ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
>         ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
>         fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
>     }
> }
> ```

- Compiled the **ShadowTest.java** using **javac ShadowTest.java**, two class files were created

  *D:\test>**javac ShadowTest.java**



   D:\test>**dir**

    Volume in drive D is MonWork

    Volume Serial Number is 3A72-52A4



    Directory of D:\test



   17-07-2021  13:01              .

   17-07-2021  13:01              ..

   17-07-2021  13:01               901 **ShadowTest$FirstLevel.class**

   17-07-2021  13:01               529 **ShadowTest.class**

   17-07-2021  13:01               539 **ShadowTest.java**

                  3 File(s)          1,969 bytes

                  2 Dir(s)  55,102,857,216 bytes free*

[output of javac command and newly created class files in the same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBc2W.png)

- On executing **ShadowTest** class, with **java ShadowTest** command. I am getting the expected output.
  **OUTPUT:**
  *D:\test>**java ShadowTest**

   x = 23

   this.x = 1

   ShadowTest.this.x = 0*
  [output of java command and its output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIofb.png)
- To reproduce your issue I tried to delete **ShadowTest$FirstLevel.class** file and execute **java ShadowTest**. But did not get the exact error you are getting.

> Error: Could not find or load main class . Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

```
*D:\test>del ShadowTest$FirstLevel.class

D:\test>java ShadowTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ShadowTest$FirstLevel
        at ShadowTest.main(ShadowTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ShadowTest$FirstLevel
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more*
```

[executing main class after deleting the class file for the inner class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfs88.png)

**Please share the complete error message and commands you are using for compiling and executing the class.**

Comment: It was just a scenario to reproduce the issue. According to the post the root cause was Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
So deleting the class file after compilation was a way to get the exception.

Comment: I just ran it the way you and it worked. I realised my mistake, the previous tutorial I did used assert statements, so instead of using -cp at the command line, I kept using -ea. My bad for the inconvenience, but learnt a lot thought, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this online [compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) ,it's executing your code error free

**your code:**

[image]

**output :**

[image]